# Unexpected system error after push was received

Tags: github

There was some github.com down time today that I wasn't aware of until I went to push about one dozen local commits.

- https://status.github.com/messages
- https://twitter.com/githubstatus

Here's the message I received when trying to push to github.com:

```
remote: Unexpected system error after push was received.
remote: These changes may not be reflected on github.com!
remote: Your unique error code: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxuz
```

Now that github.com is back up, when I view the project commit history online, I can see these dozen commits ***have not been pushed up*** to the repo.

I figured I could just push these changes again with `git push origin master`, but I am told `Everything up-to-date`. Similarily a `git pull origin master` also shows `Everything up-to-date`.

How can I get these local changes pushed up to my repo on github.com?

Comment: This happens to me right now :)

Comment: And now we have a reminder to always `pull` before `push`.

Comment: I ran into this problem yesterday, no matter what I did, the online commit history did not get updated (I got the same error constantly). Tried again today and all the commits now show up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Yen Chi, he should have made this an answer. At the least, do an empty commit:

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

Answer (score 11):

I hate to answer my own question so quickly, but with a little tinkering, here's a quick work around I discovered:

```
echo "bar" >> foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m "Add foo.txt"
git push origin master
git rm foo.txt
git commit -m "Remove foo.txt"
git push origin master
```

This properly refreshed the commit history for my github.com repo. This should be safe to do, but definitely take a backup of your local code before trying it.

Comment: You can add an empty commit with ```git commit --allow-empty```

Comment: I used `git commit --amend` to create a new hash to push up. Similar solution without actually changing anything.

Answer (score 5):

Pushing another commit for me didn't work.
Instead, creating a dummy branch, from the web interface, solved the problem.

Comment: Just had the same issue and this was the perfect resolution. I think this should be the accepted answer since it does not require littering up master with unnecessary commits.

Comment: Just had the same issue and this fixed it.  Must be a current problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this too, and yes, pushing another commit fixed the problem.

I think that the source of the problem may be that I was pulling from the same repo at the same time (I use submodules). That pull yielded everything up to date, while the first push was still hanging (and then eventually spitting out that error message).

Answer (score 1):

```
git commit --amend
git push -f origin HEAD
```

or if you don't like that

```
git commit --allow-empty
git push origin HEAD
```