# Git push failed after github went down

Tags: git, github

A few hours ago `github.com` went down for about an hour. I tried to `git push` and it says successful but this message came along with it:

```
remote: Unexpected system error after push was received.
remote: These changes may not be reflected on github.com!
remote: Your unique error code: asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasda
```

Now when I try to re-push it, it says update has failed due to the branch i'm pushing to having different files, but the ones on github is the old files. Is there anyway I can reforce it to push? :S I tried to edit some files to make the file different again, but it says the same thing.

Comment: You need to add `--force` to your push options if you're *sure* that you have the latest (and a rebase or something else isn't what's actually the cause of your divergence)

Comment: I got the same error, and the remote repo has actually received the files (I can pull them again), but they do not show up on the web interface (unless you manually put the missing revision id into the URL).

Answer (score 5):

Github uses `post-receive` [server-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) to trigger cache invalidation for most of the web resources you see by navigating the site.

`https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/commits/{branch}` is one of those views

If you go to `https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/commit/{HASH}` you will see that the commit is there and in the proper branch.

The outage might have left a lot of dangling cache jobs out there.

So, an easy way to force a `post-receive` hook trigger is to commit a simple change and `git push` it later, or else wait for Github folks to reprocess all their cached files (which might not happen).

If you are curious, you can also take a look at their [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) implementation for more details.

Comment: "The outage might have left a lot of dangling cache jobs out there." Makes sense, GitHub just went down, but now it's back up. Even though it's back up, the problem might remain for a bit longer b/c that background stuff, so might just have wait for a bit and try pushing again.

Comment: I am having this problem as well right now.... So I just wait awhile?  I added a second commit and it failed the same way...

Answer (score -3):

here's a quick work around I discovered:

```
echo "bar" >> foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m "Add foo.txt"
git push origin master
git rm foo.txt
git commit -m "Remove foo.txt"
git push origin master
```

This properly refreshed the commit history for my github.com repo. This should be safe to do, but definitely take a backup of your local code before trying it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Abin Ravi! When you find an answer elsewhere, just post the link to it as a comment, rather than copy-pasting into a new answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35052290/222356